# How can I format date in Odoo 8 QWeb report?

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

The date in my Sales Order is currently showing as:

```
Fecha: 21/11/2014 16:59:15
```

I want to show something like this:

```
Fecha: Surco, 21 de Noviembre del 2014
```

I tried using [`t-esc`](https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/web/qweb/#output) with `strftime` but that doesn't work:

```
<span t-esc="o.date_order.strftime('%Y')" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like `o.date_order` it's not a `datetime` object but a string. Using the `time` module is the way to go:

```
<span t-esc="time.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y',time.strptime(o.date_order,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"/>
```

Comment: the date format in the t-field-options attribute uses LDML pattern, so {"format": "EEEE d MMMM y"} will get the desired result. http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 17):

Try using:

```
<span t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options='{"format": "d MMMM y"}'/>
```

Result: 21 Noviembre 2014

Comment: Thank you! That's even better. But how can I format like: "Surco, 21 de Noviembre del 2014" using this method?

Comment: I am also trying to do that. I still can not.

Comment: Sad, cannot get the format from the LANG variable (or from any), since t-field-options must be a strict JSON object (not a python dict).

Answer (score 0):

Hear You can also set the custom date formate using function

**Add the function in your_report.py file**

```
class member_branch_mov(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(member_branch_mov, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'get_formate_header_date':self._get_formate_header_date      
        })


    def _get_formate_header_date(self, objects):
        header_date=''
        if self.end_date:
            date = datetime.strptime(self.end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
            header_date=date.strftime('%d  %B %Y')
        return header_date.upper()
```

hear self.end_date comes from the wizard field

**Add in your report your_report_view.xml File**

```
 <t t-if="get_formate_header_date(docs)"><span t-esc="get_formate_header_date(docs)" /></t>
```